# how do I break a comma separated string into new lines in tooltip callbacks afterBody?

Tags: chart.js

I have this string in my afterBody callbacks section of toolitps and need to break the string into new lines due to the size string can be at times. The string is dataplayernames[t[0].index] and looks like for example: name1,name2,name3,name4,name5 and my code is this.

```
tooltips: {
  // Disable the on-canvas tooltip
  enabled: true,
  mode: 'label',
  itemSort: function(a, b) {
    return b.datasetIndex - a.datasetIndex
  },
  callbacks: {
    afterBody: function(t, d) {
      return dataplayernames[t[0].index];
    }
  }
}
```

I would like it to be like this:

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
```

this image shows there are 10 players but only 9 are showing due to tooltip cut off...

[tooltip screenshot http://dodges-community.net/images/chart_10_players.png](http://dodges-community.net/images/chart_10_players.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer:

```
tooltips: {
            // Disable the on-canvas tooltip
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'point',
            itemSort: function(a, b) {
                return b.datasetIndex - a.datasetIndex
            },
            callbacks: {
                afterBody: function(t, d) {
                    if(dataplayernames[t[0].index] === ""){
                        return dataplayernames[t[0].index]+'\n\rMap: '+mapname[t[0].index]+'\n\rType: '+maptype[t[0].index];
                    }
                        else{
                            let availableData = dataplayernames[t[0].index];
                            let desiredData = replaceCommaLine(availableData);
                            function replaceCommaLine(data) {
                                //convert string to array and remove whitespace
                                let dataToArray = data.split(',').map(item => item.trim());
                                //convert array to string replacing comma with new line
                                return dataToArray.join("\n");
                            }
                            return desiredData+'\n\r\n\rMap: '+mapname[t[0].index]+'\n\rType: '+maptype[t[0].index];
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```